# Domain aliases using Amazon Route53

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have just recently started using Route53 for managing the DNS records for my domain. I own two domain names, mydomain.com and mydomain.com.au.

Is it possible to set up DNS records using Route53 such that mydomain.com.au is just simply an alias for mydomain.com. What I mean by this is that all DNS queries for xyz.mydomain.com.au will return the result of the same query for xyz.mydomain.com.

Answer (score 4):

A CNAME record would typically be used to redirect a domain to another domain.  You would simply create a CNAME record for xyz.mydomain.com.au with xyz.mydomain.com.  From the AWS Console:

1. After you've gone to your hosted zone's recordset, click on "Create Recordset".
2. In the "Name" box, type xyz.
3. In the "Type" box, select CNAME.
4. In the "Value" box, type in xyz.mydomain.com and then click the button to create the record.

Bonus:  The only scenario  that a CNAME would not work is where you wanted to redirect your root domain (i.e. mydomain.com.au) to another site, which is not supported in the DNS spec.  Route53 has a work around, but only when you use Route53 to serve DNS for a site that uses Elastic Load Balancer.